# How to configure 2 applications with separate web.configs in a website?

Tags: .net

I have 2 applications each one with a different web.config that I want to run in one website. which one of them will be configured as a virtual directory.
I can't seem to get over the configuration inheritance issue.
I have tried the location tag over the system.web and it doesn't work. or maybe I'm doing it wrong as I understand I'm suppose to put it in the web.config in the root of the website.
but I keep getting configuration errors.
anyone... ?

Comment: What error are you getting? It's possible something wrong in your config file. Also, some configurations cannot appear in more than one file.  
Please post the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert web app that stored in the virtual path to application in IIS. you can find it at below link http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/appstartpoint.asp

Answer (score 0):

An application is defined in the IIS, and web.config will be parsed for the root application (parent).
If you want another web.config, you need another application.

Answer (score 0):

o.k found it!
i guess you can't have the same connection string in both web.config's.